# Sort data from multiple rows into one row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gC07nXPRbIaYuOZ9ZFHhzpIMYz0nfa-wcpGyWhifJbA/edit?usp=sharing) containing different classes that students are scheduled into. Is there a way to consolidate all the values into one row for each student and sort the classes into their respective columns? The first two rows are what I would like the sheet to look like. One row for each student and the course columns sorted by subject.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: thank you sheet permissions updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A2:D, D2:D}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,max(Col4) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 
  pivot Col5")
```

[image]